# Retrieving information from API

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to extract information from this API: http://ex.fm/api/v3/user/dan/loved

I've done this before using the Google Maps API, however that was using `simplexml_load_file`. I tried applying the same script to this API, however it just didn't like it.

So I'm a bit clueless as to where to start. In essence, I'm trying to take the image source for each item and display it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: File is in JSON format, you need to decode it with `json_decode`

Comment: There is a JSON file ... you could use file_get_contents($path,etc.) to get the json array and use json_decode to have it as an array of objects... With it you could grab any informations you need.

Comment: Once you've used `json_decode` and `file_get_contents`, use `print_r` on the result to find out the format of the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a look here: [PHP JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://ex.fm/api/v3/user/dan/loved");
$contents = json_decode($contents);
// in order to display images
foreach ($contents->songs as $song) {
    printf("Image Small: %s\n", $song->image->small);
    printf("Image Large: %s\n", $song->image->large);
    // ...
}

// in order to store song attributes
/* $songs = array();
foreach ($contents->songs as $song) {
    $songs[] = array(
        'title' => $song->title,
        'image_small' => $song->image->small,
        // add more stuff...
    );
} */
```

Output will look like;

```
Image Small: http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/59939953.png
Image Large: http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/59939953.png
Image Small: http://www.blogcdn.com/www.spinner.com/media/2013/02/thao-with-the-get-down-stay-down-320.jpg
Image Large: http://www.blogcdn.com/www.spinner.com/media/2013/02/thao-with-the-get-down-stay-down-320.jpg
Image Small: http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mhpvhhmZbD1qz4e0mo1_1360016551_cover.jpg
Image Large: http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mhpvhhmZbD1qz4e0mo1_1360016551_cover.jpg
...
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That definitely helped me get started :)

Comment: @Alex; You're welcome. But remember doing something like this after decode: `if ($contents->status_text == 'OK') then process foreach or ...`

Answer (score 1):

Look at php's function json_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. (I haven't tested this):

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://ex.fm/api/v3/user/dan/loved");
$contents = json_decode($contents);
```

At that point you have grabbed all the data from the URL and converted it from JSON format to an array. To test it you can try either:

```
print_r($contents);
```

or

```
echo $contents['status_text'];
```

Obviously the $contents variable can be defined as whatever you like.

if you have any more troublew just comment below :)

Peter